# Zend Framework 2: Navigation (\Zend\Navigation\Navigation)

Tags: zend-framework2

I would like build a menu in Skeleton Application (ZF2). I made a separate module `Navigation`.
At Navigation Controller wrote a code:

```
namespace Navigation\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
use Zend\Navigation\Navigation;

class NavigationController extends AbstractActionController
{
public function indexAction()
{   

    $container = new \Zend\Navigation\Navigation(array(
     array(
        'label' => 'Album',
        'controller' => 'album',
        'action' => 'index',
        'route' => 'album',
         )
));

    $navigation = new \Zend\View\Helper\Navigation\Menu();

    $navigation->renderMenu($container);

    return new ViewModel(array('navigation'=>$navigation));
}}
```

And get the mistake:
`Zend\Navigation\Page\Mvc::getHref cannot execute as no Zend\Mvc\Router\RouteStackInterface instance is composed`
At file: \vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Navigation\Page\Mvc.php:186

How resolve it?

Comment: Take a look at this navigation module, as it's very well architected: https://github.com/spiffyjr/spiffy-navigation

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the route 'album' is not defined *within* your Navigation module. Routing needs to be set up in module.config.php of your Navigation module. The route needs to contain an additional parameter :module which points to the Application module, I think.

Answer (score 0):

[Click the link](https://github.com/hayk-manasyan/ZF2-NAVIGATION)

to download ZF2 dynamic navigation from database. There are functionality for add, edit, delete menu items.